# Scroll a webpage which doesn't have a scroll bar - Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried the following but still I am unable to scroll. Eg. Scroll to the 8th tile in the page.

Webpage: https://silveraisle.com/#/products?brand=Dankotuwa

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elementToScrollTo);
```

Comment: How are you locating the element? Please add that as well in the question

Comment: Which is the 8th tile in the page?

Comment: WebElement elementToScrollTo=driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//div/app-product)[8]//div/button)[1]"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elementToScrollTo);

Comment: 8th tile is the product - **Portmeirion Pomona Botanique Printed Candle**

Answer (score 0):

You can click using JavaScript on the element as workaround.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("app-product button")).get(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll till the web element

> (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
>
> WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
>
> Point point = element.getLocation();
>   JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
>
> int y = point.getY() - 200;
>
> jsExecutor.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + point.getX() + "," + y + ");", "");

Hope this will help.